# Embed API Custom Components :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewSelector2' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I try creating my own Analytics dashboard by following the link below from embed API https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/

I get this error at this line `var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2`

Where can I find the right version of the following files
1. `active-users.js`
2. `date-range-selector.js`
3. `view-selector2.js`

Please help.

the code is given below

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  });

    var commonConfig = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  };

   var dateRange1 = {
    'start-date': '14daysAgo',
    'end-date': '8daysAgo'
  };
  /
  var dateRange2 = {
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday'
  };

    var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
    container: 'view-selector-container',
  }).execute();

      var dateRangeSelector1 = new gapi.analytics.ext.DateRangeSelector({
    container: 'date-range-selector-1-container'
  })
  .set(dateRange1)
  .execute();

   var dateRangeSelector2 = new gapi.analytics.ext.DateRangeSelector({
    container: 'date-range-selector-2-container'
  })
  .set(dateRange2)
  .execute();

  var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(commonConfig)
      .set({query: dateRange1})
      .set({chart: {container: 'data-chart-1-container'}});

  var dataChart2 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(commonConfig)
      .set({query: dateRange2})
      .set({chart: {container: 'data-chart-2-container'}});

  viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
    dataChart1.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();
    dataChart2.set({query: {ids: data.ids}}).execute();

    var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
    title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';
  });

  dateRangeSelector1.on('change', function(data) {
    dataChart1.set({query: data}).execute();

    // Update the "from" dates text.
    var datefield = document.getElementById('from-dates');
    datefield.innerHTML = data['start-date'] + '&mdash;' + data['end-date'];
  });

    dateRangeSelector2.on('change', function(data) {
    dataChart2.set({query: data}).execute();

     var datefield = document.getElementById('to-dates');
    datefield.innerHTML = data['start-date'] + '&mdash;' + data['end-date'];
  });

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The source files are located in the `/build/javascript/embed-api/components` directory in the Github project. Here's a link:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/src/javascript/embed-api/components
All you have to do is download those files and add them to your page.

If you look at the source of the demo you referenced, you'll notice it contains the following lines:

```
<!-- Include the ViewSelector2 component script. -->
<script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js"></script>

<!-- Include the DateRangeSelector component script. -->
<script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js"></script>
```

The location `/public/javascript/embed-api/components/` is where they're being hosted on the demo. You can choose whatever file path you want, but they must be on the page of you'll keep getting an error.

Comment: I got the files from the same directory and added to my location. Do i need to include the following files too   
1. view-selector2.js.map   
2. date-range-selector.js.map

Comment: You don't *need* them, but they're nice to have for debugging. If you don't have them everything will still work fine.

Comment: To Debug, I added both .map files and  I got the error
view-selector2.js.map:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
date-range-selector.js.map: 
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
custom_script.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewSelector2' of undefined

Comment: The custom components need to be loaded first. Are you doing that? Short of that, I think you'll need to debug this on your own. When you're getting that a property is not defined, that means you're not actually running the code that defines it. Use the developer tools, and put in `console.log` statement to see what's actually being run and what's not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philip for the guidance. Charts are rendered. yay!! I will debug the the error.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you then you should upvote it or mark it as accepted so other people with the same question can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `viewSelector` from:

```
var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
  container: 'view-selector-container',
}).execute();
```

to

```
var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
  container: 'view-selector-container'
});

viewSelector.execute();
```

Comment: @ casper : tried it, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Casper doing this will load a different view selector. Presumably the OP wanted to use `ViewSelector2` for a reason.

Comment: Yeah i figurred that out after posting my answer, I'm also still new to the Google API,thought i could give a correct answer, I we're worng, my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can include that components like this:

```
<!-- Include the ViewSelector2 component script. -->
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js"></script>

<!-- Include the DateRangeSelector component script. -->
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js"></script>
```

This way the rest of the code in the example doesn't have to be changed.